# Is that the type of browser is important when using karma?

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

I'm a Karma beginner, and I was wondering if the type of browser (firefox, chrome, phantom etc.) does really matter, because all the results will be displayed on the terminal.

Could anyone tells me why we should bother with the browser ?

Comment: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/browsers.html

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't explain why we should choose specific browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reasons why you want to choose a browser for testing: first of all cross-browser compatibility.

Once you've created your web-app you want that the behavior of your functions/features are consistent on any browser you are expecting from your customer base.
If you want to be more specific: IE most of the time is what you want to test.

Note that if you are running covering metrics on your tests, some branches of the code might be executed only by some specific browser agents (and versions) sometimes.

Sometimes it's convenient run your tests on some headless browser (such PhantomJS) to run faster (even though I'm not sure it's faster than Chrome on Karma, due to [a known issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/494))